# GCC's Warning in Boost Source

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost 1.63 and when I compile my application that includes `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>`.

GCC complains:

```
In file included from /opt/boost/boost/mpl/aux_/na_assert.hpp:23,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/mpl/arg.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/range/iterator_range.hpp:13,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/range/as_literal.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp:19,
                 from /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:19,
         from [my source that includes <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>]
/opt/boost/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:188:21: warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of ‘assert_arg’ [-Wparentheses]
 failed ************ (Pred::************
                     ^
/opt/boost/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:193:21: warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of ‘assert_not_arg’ [-Wparentheses]
 failed ************ (boost::mpl::not_<Pred>::************
                     ^
```

I looked at the source and complained section is:

```
template< typename Pred >
failed ************ (Pred::************
      assert_arg( void (*)(Pred), typename assert_arg_pred<Pred>::type )
    );

template< typename Pred >
failed ************ (boost::mpl::not_<Pred>::************
      assert_not_arg( void (*)(Pred), typename assert_arg_pred_not<Pred>::type )
    );
```

Questions:

- what is `failed ************ (Pred::************`?  The syntax looks weird to me.
- how I can fix it without suppressing all similar warnings?  As GCC's warnings are usually valid and helpful in detecting issues.

I searched online, and the closest, related one is [this](https://git.idrol.net/idrol/VoxelRPG/issues/28).  But its solution seems to just suppress the warnings.

Thanks!

Comment: Unnecessary parens is absolutely a warning and not any sort of error. It just means that, while the syntax is valid, the parens do not _need_ to be there. What's your command line?

Comment: There is `BOOST_MPL_IGNORE_PARENTHESES_WARNING` macro (at least in recent boost) to suppress this message. `failed ********` looks like a pointer declaration.

Comment: @Qix I was using cmake, and it generated something like `-I/opt/boost/boost`.  I agree that it is a warning.  But I want to turn on `-Werror`.

Comment: @VTT that's an interesting solution.  But I just did `grep -r "BOOST_MPL_IGNORE_PARENTHESES_WARNING" .` in `/opt/boost` where my boost lives.  And it has nothing.  Probably boost 1.63 doesn't have it yet.

Comment: CMake can generate `-isystem` flags as per @NikosC's answer.  Just use the `SYSTEM` argument. i.e.: `target_include_directories(myapp SYSTEM PUBLIC "/opt/boost/boost")`

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thanks for confirming.  Yes, I just tried with `include_directories(SYSTEM /opt/boost)`.  It works.  Didn't know that gcc has `-isystem`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally GCC and Clang automatically suppress warnings from headers in `/usr`. However, it seems that for `/opt` it doesn't. To tell the compiler that the boost headers should be treated as system headers, use `-isystem` instead of `-I` to add the boost headers to the include paths.